# Find stdev of values in col B where col A matches criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a sheet where column A is dates and column B is values. I want to find the stdev of values in B where the date in A is within the last 30 days.

I am able to do sums with a `sumifs` which works on ranges. `stdev` works on a range but I need a way to tell it to only select values from B where A matches a criteria and then return the list of matches... I thought maybe `filter` was the right function, but I cant seem to get the conditions right to return what I want. I think something like `A&">today()-30"` or something works for the condition, but only when it's asking for a "criterion" and not a "condition".

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this problem can be solved by using the `FILTER()` function. Assuming your data is stored in the range `A1:B62`, with dates in column `A` and values in column `B`, the first row being the headers, and the data running from, e.g., 01/05/2023 to 30/06/2023. The procedure using the `FILTER()` function looks as follows:

```
=FILTER($B$1:$B$62,$A$1:$A$62>=TODAY()-30)
```

First, you specify the array that you want to return, i.e., your values in column `B`. The second part specifies, which values you want to include, i.e., only those that have a date that is in the last 30 days in column `A`. In the current specification, this includes the value of "Today" and thus returns 31 values assuming that every day is available. If you want to include only historical values, then you can adjust the function as follows, to restrict it also on the upper end:

```
=FILTER($B$1:$B$62,($A$1:$A$62>=TODAY()-30)*($A$1:$A$62<TODAY()))
```

Using this specification, you return the same values as above, but exclude the value of "Today" and thus return 30 days assuming all days are available. The additional constraint is that the date needs to be less than `TODAY()`.

To compute the standard deviation (SD), you simply need to wrap the `STDEV()` function of your choice around the filter function:

```
=STDEV(FILTER($B$1:$B$62,($A$1:$A$62>=TODAY()-30)*($A$1:$A$62<TODAY())))
```

---

The procedure outlined above works under the assumption that you want to compute the SD only once for the past 30 days. A potentially more real-world example would be the computation of the SD in a moving way as a row-by-row computation considering always the past 30 values available in your data (consider, e.g., trading days or similar). This scenario could be tackled with the `BYROW()` function, which looks in its general form as follows:

```
=BYROW(array, [function])
```

Thus, we need to specify the array we want to apply the function to, with the function specified in the lambda statement. In its basic specification (formula in e.g., cell `C2` as it is an array formula) applied under the assumptions above the procedure looks as follows:

```
=BYROW($B$2:$B$62,
LAMBDA(row,STDEV(OFFSET(row,,,-30))))
```

First, we specify the array based on which we want to apply the function  and then define the function in the lambda statement. Given that we want to apply the SD computation on the past 30 days, we `OFFSET()` a given row by a height of -30 to capture this.

However, the current specification has two fallacies: (i) you get a `#REF!` error in the first 29 rows because of the -30 offset and (ii) the computation of the SD in row 30 contains only 29 values because the first row is the header, i.e., a text cell. Thus, to circumvent these issues, we can adjust the formula as follows including an `IF()` with `COUNTIF()` and `IFERROR()` statement:

```
=BYROW($B$2:$B$62,
LAMBDA(row,IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(row,,,-30),"*")>0,"",STDEV(OFFSET(row,,,-30))),"")))
```

The former takes care of the issue of computing the SD with 29 values and the latter takes care of the `#REF!` errors. Using this approach, you have the row-by-row computation of the SD of the last 30 days available.